# C# Creating a generic type validator service

Tags: c#, validation, service, interface

I have a structure of people in an enterprise like Boss and Employee.

I just added Validator on each type to apply rules before moving forward with creation.

```
public class BossService : IStructMapper<People>
{
    IValidatorService<Boss> _validatorService;

    public BossService(IValidatorService<Boss> validatorService)
    {
        _validatorService = validatorService;
    }

    public List<Boss> Convert(string json)
    {
        var bossSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<boss>>(json);

        bossSource.ForEach(x => x.ApplyRules());

        _validatorService.ValidateContent(new BossValidator(), bossSource);
    }
}


public class BossValidatorService : IValidatorService<Boss>
{

    public void ValidateContent(AbstractValidator<Boss> validator, List<Boss> bossContent)
    {
         foreach (var item in bossContent)
            {
                var result = validator.Validate(item);
                if (result.IsValid) continue;
            }
    }
}

public interface IValidatorService<T>
{
    void ValidateContent(AbstractValidator<T> validator, List<T> content);
}


public class BossValidator : AbstractValidator<Boss>
{
    public BossValidator()
    {
         ***rules for boss**
    }
}
```

so in my program I call and it does it's job:

```
var bosses = new BossService(new BossValidatorService()).Convert(datafile)
```

For employee I created distinct EmployeeService class and EmployeeValidator :

```
public class EmployeeService : IStructMapper<People>
{
    IValidatorService<Employee> _validatorService;

    public EmployeeService(IValidatorService<Employee> validatorService)
    {
        _validatorService = validatorService;
    }

    public List<Employee> Convert(string json)
    {
        var employeeSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(json);

        employeeSource .ForEach(x => x.ApplyRules());

        _validatorService.ValidateContent(new BossValidator(), bossSource);
    }
}

public class EmployeeValidator : AbstractValidator<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeValidator()
        {
             ***rules for employee**
        }
    }
```

How can I simplify my code to not have to create a BossValidatorService, an EmployeeValidatorService, a ConsultantValidatorService, etc. since the ValidateContent function will be the same for each type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the Type to the Class and use Generics as intended. I did not go to running code but it should be clear to you how to use:

```
var bosses = new Service<Boss>(new ValidatorService<Boss, BossValidator>()).Convert(datafile)

public class Service<T, TValidator> : IStructMapper<People> where TValidator : new()
    {
        IValidatorService<T> _validatorService;

        public Service(IValidatorService<T> validatorService)
        {
            _validatorService = validatorService;
        }

        public List<T> Convert(string json)
        {
            var Source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

            Source.ForEach(x => x.ApplyRules());

            _validatorService.ValidateContent(new TValidator<T>(), Source);
        }
    }


    public class ValidatorService<T> : IValidatorService<T> 
    {

        public void ValidateContent(AbstractValidator<T> validator, List<T> Content)
        {
            foreach (var item in Content)
            {
                var result = validator.Validate(item);
                if (result.IsValid) continue;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IValidatorService<T>
    {
        void ValidateContent(AbstractValidator<T> validator, List<T> content);
    }


    public class BossValidator : AbstractValidator<Boss>
    {
        public BossValidator()
        {
            ***rules for boss * *
        }
    }



    public class EmployeeValidator : AbstractValidator<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeValidator()
        {
            ***rules for employee * *
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works it is just the Source.ForEach(x => x.ApplyRules()); that is not working something not working with type I will check tomorrow what's going wrong.

Comment: If you are happy with this please mark as answered.

Comment: Currently : Source.ForEach(x => x.ApplyRules()); is not working as I don't have access to ApplyRules on x and the _validatorService.ValidateContent(new TValidator<T>(), placeSource); is not taking the new TValidator  that is why I did not mark as solved yet

Comment: I think what you want is a method on the validator class, so this class needs method ApplyRules and you pass on the Boss object..